# How do I import cpp to objective-c

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, namespaces

I created a .h and a .cpp file in my project.

```
//  TestClass.h

namespace testNamepace {

  class TestClass {
      int num;
  };
}
```

When I imported TestClass.h to ViewController.h and compiled the project, it said Unknown type name 'namespace'.

```
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TestClass.h"
using namespace testNamepace;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

I have already changed extension of ViewController.m to .mm

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like your header is included in some .m file. you may wanna rename those as well.

Comment: C++ provides the 'extern "C"' facility so that a C++ function can be used by a C program. And you're missing it. Also even if you rename file to .mm, I'm not sure if Xcode switches type of this file to C++. Select this file in navigator, click on it, open utilities side bar and change file type to ObjC++. Do this for the C++ header file as well.

Comment: Here's some article about mixing C, C++ - http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/mixing.html#cpp_from_c

Comment: you should know the levels of the C language is the following (_draft version_): `C -> Objective C -> Objective C++` and on separated thread `C -> C++`. so you can see there is no direct way to add a pure `C++` code to an `Objective C` project. you have to convert it to `Objective C++` or `Objective C` before you want to use — or you would compile a library from the `C++` code and you can import it into your project, but this is bit risky way if you want to publish the project in the AppStore, the Apple does not like the third part libraries.

Comment: @jakev, you misunderstood the meaning of the phrase _3rd party library_, and **yes**, you will need to avoid to use any 3rd party libraries in your project, if you want to make your application AppStore-safe. it is highly possible to develop almost every type of application without using any _3rd party library_. I guess you mixed the definitions only, and I assume what you think of what that phrase means is _source-code-created-by-somebody-else_ but that is not a _3rd party library_. that is what I'm talking about.

Comment: @jakev, oh, you think you know what it means, fine. please, tell me, which 3rd party libraries you are using right now, and please tell me, why _almost impossible to create an interesting app without any_. please, don't confuse yourself, because it is dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .h file is recognized as C or Obj-C, which may be the cause of you error.

Xcode maintain an index of each file to know how they must be compiled. You can change this in the inspector (I don't really remember and don't have Xcode anymore).

Another solution which may work is to use extern "C++" declaration to wrap your header code.

For example:

```
extern "C++" {
namespace test {

class MyClass;    

}
}
```